# CSS covering a div with other that got opacity set with css

Tags: html, css

Hi Folks Here is what i got in css:

```
#loading {
 background:#000 url(loading.png) center;
 opacity:0.5;
 cursor:auto;
 min-height:250px;
 z-index:15;
}

#main {
 padding: 10px;
 z-index:1;
}
```

and in  html:

```
<div id="loading">
      <div id="main">Something here</div>
</div>
```

and i expect the loading.png to cover the div#main but it doesn't and "Something here" stays on the top of loading.png !?

Update: background is in CSS not an image in  loading div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is wrong. The div `main` should be *outside* the div `loading`:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="loading"></div>
  Something here
</div>
```

You also need to position the latter div using CSS so that it does not just push the main content out from underneath it, as well as sizing the div at 100% of its container's width and height:

```
#main { position: relative; }

#loading {
 background: url("loading.png");
 opacity: 0.5;
 cursor:auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index:15;

 /* Positioning */
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
}
```

Comment: @idealmachine - Shouldn't the positioning be relative instead of absolute? Otherwise, it may not be located over the #main div. Also top: 50% and left: 50%?

Comment: @shamazing: Yes for the first part.

Comment: The spelling correction helped with opacity of image in background, but the `position: absolute` didn't worked !! the content in main is dynamic so is the height, and i wan't the loading to cover all of it not just on part of it.

Comment: It should also be noted that not all browsers support min-height.

Comment: @Omeid Herat: I've edited the code above. Does the new version work? http://jsfiddle.net/g6gJG/1/

Comment: Add width:100%; height:100%; to your CSS for the loading DIV to have it cover entirely.

Comment: @idealmachine: Thanks for code, it worked but it covers the whole page not the Div main only.

Comment: @Omeid Herat: You do have the `#main { position: relative; }` line in, right? Otherwise the absolute position is relative to the entire page, not the outer div.

Comment: @idealmachine: Yup its, but still it covers the page, and something else i use the image in background not the image element.

Comment: @Omeid Herat: Which browser are you testing in? http://jsfiddle.net/g6gJG/3/ works for me in the latest non-beta versions of IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera (although the overlaid div is fully opaque in IE because it doesn't support the CSS opacity property).

Comment: Will i tested in Chrome,Firefox and IE and I am wondering that  did you looked at the update ? the image is not an element its a property in css.

Comment: @Omeid Herat: I made this test page http://jsfiddle.net/g6gJG/3/ and it works in all the browsers I name above. This latest version of the page uses background-image; I just forgot to update the code in my posted answer.